# Stored procedure starting with #

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, trace

I was running a trace on an application today and saw this for the first time ever, in the text data of the trace:

```
exec #spDMF1F848FB98D743F69BA4AF02A7C05927
```

Can't seem to find anything online anywhere. I am guessing that it is some kind of temp procedure that the application built in background, but that is a complete guess and never have heard that was even possible.

Running SQL Server 2005, SQL Server Management Studio v15.0.18384.0

Anyone familiar with anything similar?

Comment: It's a temporary object, in this case a temporary procedure. Just like a temporary table, it lasts for as long as the scope that created it does.

Comment: Also, are you *really* using SQL Server 2005? Your about 5 years over due an upgrade, as it's been completely unsupported for some time.

Comment: Yeah. It is truly a sad situation. It is running an old ERP system and that is the latest version that it supports.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the info.

Comment: i think jtds is using these things (among others) to handle binding of parameters. But could be anything really